# Can't get docker start on Ubuntu?

Tags: docker, ubuntu

This is what I have:

---

> suyashdew@DESKTOP-DPRQ445:~$ lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

> suyashdew@DESKTOP-DPRQ445:~$ docker version

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.1
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.6
 Git commit:        4c52b90
 Built:             Wed Jan  9 19:35:23 2019
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I am new to *nix systems and I am trying to work on it. Please help!

Note:  I have tried

> sudo service docker start

```
 * Starting Docker: docker
```

> sudo service docker status

```
 * Docker is not running
```

I have tried several ways mentioned in other threads but nothing worked. One of the ways broke the docker-ce and I had to remove it from the package and then re-install it. And it still can't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't connect because you're not the `root` user and you're not in the `docker` group. Make sure to follow the [Linux post-install instructions](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/), and don't forget to re-start your computer after adding yourself to the `docker` group.

---

You can verify whether this is the problem or not before trying all of that - does `sudo docker version` work?

Comment: I tried that and I have already put it on the question above. I added a little more details to the question. Hope you can suggest me some ways. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

might be a permission issue.

This are the postinstallation steps for linux:
[docker post installation](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/linux-postinstall/)

you could  try with sudo.

if you've the same issue with sudo, try

`service docker status`
and 
`service docker start`